# How to find best no of clusters for clustering algorithm using categorical data

Tags: cluster-analysis, categorical-data

I am working on categorical data with multiple features and i am stuck knowing the best number of clusters for my data set.

Is there any ways to find best K for categorical data clustering.

I have used the K-modes where we need to specify the no of clusters but this doesn't solve the problem.

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Is this somewhere closely related to K Means clustering?

Comment: @silentsudo : Not really,as k-means uses distance matrix like Euclidean distance measure, Manhattan distance measure but we cannot use these matrix for comparing the distance of categorical variables

Answer (score 0):

Well, clustering really isn't designed for ordinal data.  I would suggest that you take a look at OHE.  Check out this code sample.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
X = [['Male', 1], ['Female', 3], ['Female', 2]]
enc.fit(X)

enc.categories_

enc.transform([['Female', 1], ['Male', 4]]).toarray()

enc.inverse_transform([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])

enc.get_feature_names(['gender', 'group'])

drop_enc = OneHotEncoder(drop='first').fit(X)
drop_enc.categories_

drop_enc.transform([['Female', 1], ['Male', 2]]).toarray()
```

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Or, you can use an OE.  Here is more sample code.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
enc = OrdinalEncoder()
X = [['Male', 1], ['Female', 3], ['Female', 2]]
enc.fit(X)

enc.categories_

enc.transform([['Female', 3], ['Male', 1]])
```

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder

Finally, you may consider using Affinity Propagation, Hierarchical Clustering, or DBSCAN; links below.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_affinity_propagation.html

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_agglomerative_dendrogram.html

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html

I don't think the results will be meaningful or relevant for clustering categorical datasets.  What is the 'distance' between red, blue, and green?  Make sense?

Comment: I have been doing more research on the categorical data clustering these days and could find few results like k-medioids, Rock and k-modes.                                 
 Steps involved  are:                                                                                                     a) I have found a dissimalirity matrix using gower distance                                        
b)I have performed clustering on the data using k-medioids                                               c)I have checked the performance of clustering using silhouette_score